# Is Visual source safe 2005 compatible in windows server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2012, visual-sourcesafe, windows-server-2016, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I was trying to install visual source safe 2005 software in windows server 2016 , I am getting compatibility error. As shown in the below image .

Just wanted to check if VSS 2005 is compatible with windows server 2016 or windows server 2012.

[image: VSS Installation Error]

[image: VSS Installation Error]